# How to add title excel in Laravel using Yajra?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, yajra-datatable

How to add title when exporting to excel in Laravel using Yajra?

```
->parameters([
            'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
            'order' => [[4, "desc"]],
            //'buttons' => ['excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
            'buttons' => [
                [
                    'extend' => 'excel',
                    'title' => "adjfadfjad"
                ],
                [
                    'extend' => 'pdf'
                ],
                [
                    'extend' => 'print',
                    'title' => "adjfadfjad"
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

I tried adding title but it's failed, not working, how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Add like this: title or message on top:

->parameters([
            `dom` => 'Bfrtip',
            'order' => [[4, "desc"]],
            'buttons' => [
                {
                extend: 'excel',
                messageTop: 'Title Information'}
            ],
        ]);